# Is there any way to disable a admin page in starpi?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am using strapi framework in one of my project.
After development, I need to disable the admin dashboard ('/admin' route).
I found the ways to change the URL, but not to disable.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to disable the admin in production.

You can rename the `admin` folder with `_admin` (or delete the folder)
Update the `plugin/users-permissions/middlewares/users-permissions/index.js` file and comment these lines:

```
// _.forEach(strapi.admin.config.routes, value => {
//   if (_.get(value.config, 'policies')) {
//     value.config.policies.unshift('plugins.users-permissions.permissions');
//   }
// });
```

Then you will not be able to access to the admin pannel