# how to disable strapi admin dashboard in beta?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I read this [Is there any way to disable a admin page in starpi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643597/is-there-any-way-to-disable-a-admin-page-in-starpi) which I believe works fine in `alpha`

since the structure in `beta` changed, I tried adding this `extensions/users-permissions/middlewares/users-permissions/index.js` then copied the original `node_modules/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/admin/src/index.js` and commented what was suggested in the that post's answer

```
        // _.forEach(strapi.admin.config.routes, value => {
        //     if (_.get(value.config, 'policies')) {
        //         value.config.policies.unshift(
        //             'plugins.users-permissions.permissions'
        //         );
        //     }
        // });
```

I rebuild with `yarn build` but I can still access the admin dashboard though.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Once you fixed this then please share, How you do this with each steps. It may helps others and me too. :)

Comment: @SachinShah After lots of digging I actually found a way but not sure if it's the best, what I did was empty the login page.  So path still exist but the page is totally empty

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the best way but after digging more that I found out how to overwrite the original page's code, so what I did below is emptied the whole login page but path still exists.

Once knowing where the file is located, it's easy with three steps

1. create file `project_root/admin/src/containers/AuthPage/index.js`
2. inside the newly created file paste `export default memo(() => {});`
3. run the build e.g. `yarn build`

now try to access the admin page again `localhost:1337/admin` the page would be empty.

P.S. if you don't want to just empty the page then write your own code inside the `index.js` created but remember, any edits you need to run a build in order to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete the `.cache` and the `build` folders and start your application with the following command:

`yarn develop --no-build` it will disable the admin completely.